# How to get rid of pixelated edges of a jpg?

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, bitmap, transparency

For my student project, I’ve a vb.net code snippet that downloads a jpg file from a website and then sets all its pixels, which are almost white, entirely white:

```
Dim oColor As Color
Dim bRed As Byte
Dim bGreen As Byte
Dim bBlue As Byte

Dim imgTemp As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\DownloadedImage.jpg")
Dim bmpTemp As New Bitmap(imgTemp.Width, imgTemp.Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

Using gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpTemp)
    gfx.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    gfx.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
    gfx.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
    gfx.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
    gfx.DrawImage(imgTemp, 0, 0)
End Using

For x = 0 To bmpTemp.Width - 1
    For y = 0 To bmpTemp.Height - 1

       oColor = bmpTemp.GetPixel(x, y)
       bRed = oColor.R
       bGreen = oColor.G
       bBlue = oColor.B

       If bRed <= 254 AndAlso bRed >= 254 - 20 Then '20 = White Tolerance'
          bmpTemp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White)
       End If

       If bGreen <= 254 AndAlso bGreen >= 254 - 20 Then
          bmpTemp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White)
       End If

       If bBlue <= 254 AndAlso bBlue >= 254 - 20 Then
          bmpTemp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White)
       End If

    Next
Next

Dim newForm As New Form With {.BackgroundImage = bmpTemp, .TransparencyKey = Color.White, .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom, .BackColor = Color.White}

newForm.Show()
```

The bitmap created in this way is then set as the BackgroundImage of a form whose TransparencyKey property is white. The result is not a complete failure, but the edges of the isolated object are still white and pixelated:

[The result in two different sizes (left) and what I'm trying to achieve (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQBmz.jpg)

I’m now looking for a way to get rid of those ragged edges, something like Photoshop’s “Refine Edge” function.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know how to do any of this in vb.net, but you need an alpha channel to accomplish this. The alpha value should be 1 (totally transparent) for white pixels, and proportionally lower for values further away from white. You cannot solve this without an alpha channel unless you know what the background color will be.

Comment: @CrisLuengo : The [**`TransparencyKey` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx) of a form/window in .NET will make whatever color you give it transparent. It works (as seen in his image) because all white pixels in the rest of the image are gone. However those closest to the ball are not fully white (which is what his code tries to do), thus they are not made transparent.

Comment: OP: Have you checked some of those pixels in an image editor and verified that they are/aren't within the tolerated range?

Comment: @VisualVincent : I understand the problem. What I'm saying is that you can't have a transparent background without a pixelated edge unless you use an actual alpha channel (rather than binary transparent or opaque), or you know what the color of the background will be that the image will be rendered on.

Comment: @CrisLuengo : Oh I see what you mean now, sorry for my confusion. Yes, you're right. However I think what the OP is trying to do is to turn them completely white (thus in the result completely transparent), but apparently they do not meet the tolerance standards which is what the OP needs to check.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks for your reply, Vincent! I looked into the topic and it seems like the alpha channel, as suggested by CrisLuengo, is the right idea. The (almost) white edge remains, even though I increased the white tolerance so that all its pixels are within the tolerated range (checked with an image editor). My aim was indeed to turn them completely white so TransparencyKey makes them transparent. Does that mean there is no way for this code to work without an image with an alpha channel?

Comment: I don't think you are forced to use an alpha channel, your code should be working... Either way, even if it gives you a smoother look creating an image where you swap the white with its relative alpha is _**much**_ harder than what you're doing now.

Comment: If I get the time I'll test the code.